# Nuget.exe command CLI does not recognized

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package

I would like to add feed to push my nuget package to Azure Devops as artifacts. I have followed all the steps that have been mentioned in the Microsoft docs to push my nuget package to Azure Devops. I have downloaded nuget.exe CLI and it is sit in the same folder in which i have generated/built my project nuget packages. However why m I getting the following error and i searched quite a bit everywhere but could not find any answer:-

Build nuget package and nuget.exe CLI folder path:-

```
C:\Users\Desktop\MyProjects\ProjectName> Under this folder I have following files
   --nuget.exe 
   --AutoOnWeb.Messaging.Helpers.2.1.0.nupkg
```

Command to Execute(Add this feed):

```
Path: C:\Users\Desktop\MyProjects\ProjectName>    
    nuget.exe sources Add -Name "AutoShop.Messaging.Helpers" -Source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/HelpersLibrary/_packaging/AutoShop.Messaging.Helpers/nuget/v3/index.json"
```

Error:-

```
nuget.exe : The term 'nuget.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nuget.exe sources Add -Name "InfrastructureMessagingHelpers" -Source  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nuget.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have downloaded and installed all required framework libraries.

Thanks,

Comment: in powershell you don't call files in the local directory like that but like this: "&.\nuget.exe"

Comment: wow! I did not realize that i am running command in PowerShell CLI environment and then i was searching like a hell. I can't believe this.... Thanks buddy

Comment: You can also use Azure DevOps NuGet task to push, so you don't have to download nuget.exe or call it yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops#push-nuget-packages

Answer (score 0):

> Nuget.exe command CLI does not recognized

That because NuGet is a external command, can not be recognized by Windows in an arbitrary directory, that is the reason why it is not recognized.

To resolve this issue, you should type the "NuGet" or "NuGet.exe" in the path where NuGet.exe exists. For you case, you can switch path to `C:\Users\Desktop\MyProjects\ProjectName>` when you calls nuget.exe.

Alternatively, you could download the NuGet.exe (Not VSIX) from NuGet.org and **set the local path of NuGet.exe into your path environment variable**. In this case, you call the nuget.exe directly in the powershell scripts.

Hope this helps.